# Can't select quotas in google console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

This is really strange because I have request GPU quotas before without problem.

However when I tried to select quotas by clicking the box, it won't respond at all, any one have same error? This look like A/B test from google for new console. Because on my account, the UI is differrent and I can still click the boxes.[image]

Comment: This is working as expected for me. Which browser/version are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome but I doubt that is the problem, because on my main account it still work fine. ( same browser / machine )

Comment: In that case I would suggest you to open a new [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: You can click (and check) or you can't change the quotas? (of course, if you can't click, you can't change quotas!)